# Drupal: Render form in block tpl

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-fapi, drupal-forms

How do I render a form, which is part of a renderable array?

In .module

```
/**
 * Implements hook_block_view();
 */
function bibdk_vejviser_block_view($delta = '') {

  switch ($delta) {
    case 'bibdk_vejviser':
      $block['title'] = t('Find Library');
      $block['content'] = array(
        'link' => array(
          '#type' => 'link',
          '#title' => t("Find library"),
          '#href' => 'http://example.org',
        ),
        'form' => drupal_get_form('bibdk_vejviser_form'),
      );
      break;
  }
  return $block;
}
```

In custom block .tpl

```
// This will work (renders both elements)
print $content;

// This will also work (renders link)
print render($elements['link']);

// This will NOT work (renders nothing)
print render($elements['form']);
```

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:
It works if I wrap drupal_get_form() in an array. Why is that??

```
...
'form' => array(drupal_get_form('bibdk_vejviser_form')),
...
```

Answer (score 1):

It should work when you wrap `drupal_get_form` with `drupal_render`

Something like that:

```
...
'form' => array(
'#markup' => drupal_render(drupal_get_form('bibdk_vejviser_form'))),
...
```

Hope this works... Muhammad.

Comment: Hmm.. it's not working here. And besides - the solution would return a string, which would not be true to the render array philosophy. In my solution you would be able to alter the form with hook_block_view_alter too.